# Where are environment variables of a process is stored in linux?

Tags: c, linux, stack, kernel

I have made a simple C program like:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
        char *str;
        int i = 1;
        char *ptr = "Sample string";  // Stored in Data segment
        if (ac == 2)
        {
                str = malloc(len(av[1]) + 1);
                strcpy(str, av[1]);
        }

        printf("The address of %s is %p\n",ptr,ptr);
        while (i)

        {
                printf("[%d] %s - addr: %p\n", i, str, str);
                sleep(1);
                i++;
        }
        free(str);
        return (0);
}

int len(char *str)
{
        int i;

        for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
                ;
        return (i);
}
```

Now I made another program to look into memory (especially stack) of another program, and I read the data using `process_vm_readv` . When I print the stack of this process, I get all this information : processes is called `tobe` and I called it as `./tobe "Yo Boys"`

```
=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36/home/mohit05/code2/
```

If the above is unreadable , here is another copy: [image: The output]
My doubt is if all these variables and data are stored in stack itself or am I running to some other memory.
I got range of stack using `/proc/{pid}/maps` and then read the whole of that using `process_vm_readv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On modern Linux systems, environment values are "kind-of" stored on the stack -- for specific values of "kind-of".

The actual strings that make up the environment are stored at the top (highest-numbered addresses) of the process's virtual address space, along with other environmental data. The stack proper begins immediately below this. The addresses of the individual environment variables are pushed onto the stack by the kernel's program loader, along with the `argc` and `argv` values.

This close correspondence between the environment and the stack leads many writers to talk about the environment being "on the stack" although, strictly speaking, only the addresses of the specific environment values are properly on the stack. Diagrams of the Linux process address space often show the stack at the top of memory, although if you run `pmap` on a process, you'll see that this isn't usually the case -- there will be one or two segments above the stack proper, and the environment variables will be found in one of these.

Comment: So based on that, I can safely say that the data which I have extracted is from the process stack itself? I have been having a doubt if I am reading somewhere other then stack.

Comment: I don't know. If you read upwards from the stack, you'll eventually reach the environment. Whether you're still reading within the stack depends on where the top of the stack is.

Comment: Example: `7ffffe662000-7ffffe683000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]` is address range I got from `proc/pid/maps` and I am reading this range only. If it would be of any help, You would like me to share my program via which I am reading.